# Inviting friends from facebook to android app using WebDialog Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a friend picker fragment for picking friends. Once done, I'm trying to populate the friends obtained in the WebDialog by providing 'to' parameter but friends list that I provided in the "to" array is not populated in the WebDialog. I'm using facebook 3.0 sdk for Android

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", getString(R.string.request_message));
params.putStringArray("to", fbIdArray);

    Builder builder = new WebDialog.Builder(PickFriendsActivity.this,
            Session.getActiveSession(), "apprequests", params);
builder.build().show();
```

Anything that needs to be done differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apprequest dialog doesn't take non-string parameters, so you need to turn your array into a comma separated list like:

```
"ID_1,ID_2,ID_3,..."
```